# Where is Bluetooth pairing stored

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-3, ubuntu

I have paired a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse with my Pi3 running Raspbian.

I am setting up Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on another SD Card to run on the same Pi3.

I would like to use the keyboard and mouse on both distributions. I expect this is possible, as I am using the same hardware.

I guess if I pair on Ubuntu this will break pairing on Raspbian (or will it)?

Where is the Bluetooth pairing stored on Raspbian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pairings are stored in /var/lib/bluetooth, but I have not tested if they're easily transferable to another system. You will certainly need to change the top directory to match system's bluetooth MAC.

In below example "A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF" is RPI's MAC, "B0:A3:E6:A3:8B:A4" is a paired peripheral:

```
# find /var/lib/bluetooth/
/var/lib/bluetooth/
/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF
/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF/settings
/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF/B0:A3:E6:A3:8B:A4
/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF/B0:A3:E6:A3:8B:A4/info
/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF/cache
/var/lib/bluetooth/A4:37:FB:E3:AC:CF/cache/B0:A3:E6:A3:8B:A4
```

Comment: For my Pi, I have 2 MicroSDs with Raspbian. 

I back up the pairings on card 1:
    sudo tar zcf bluetooth_pairings.tgz /var/lib/bluetooth
and restore them on card 2:
    sudo tar xzf bluetooth_pairings.tgz -C /

Works for me!